# How to get usernames of all users with object ids in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is my data structure,

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e38e95a5c50fe7afb44866b"),
        "username" : "user9",
        "name" : "user9",
        "email" : "user9@testing.com",
        "password" : "testing11",
        "dateOfBirth" : ISODate("1992-12-29T13:00:00Z"),
        "gender" : "Male",
        "location" : "Melbourne",
        "relationshipStatus" : "Married",
        "visibilityStatus" : 3,
        "friends" : [
                ObjectId("5e38e9175c50fe7afb448667"),
                ObjectId("5e38e92a5c50fe7afb448668"),
                ObjectId("5e38e9405c50fe7afb448669"),
                ObjectId("5e38e94c5c50fe7afb44866a")
        ],
        "friendRequests" : [ ]
}
```

So basically in friends array I push in the object id but I need to know how to aggregate so I can get the list of names using their object id so a query that would give the result - ['user5', 'user6', 'user7', 'user8'] or something similar which are the friends to this user

Comment: can you share friends collection?

Comment: You can use `$lookup` to make a self join and get the names for the friends (assuming you are looking for the `name` within the same collection).

Comment: Yes but I want to do it for just one user when I do the lookup it gives me names for all users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.Users.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id: loggedInUser._id}},
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'Users',
            localField: 'friends',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'showFriends'
        }
    },
    {$group:{
            _id:"$_id",
            friends:{$push:'$showFriends.username'},
        }
    }
]);
```

I figured it out thanks to the answer from Mr. Gandhi. I needed to use group.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:-

```
db.user.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$friends"},
    {$lookup: { 
        from: "user",
        localField: "friends",
        foreignField: "id",
        as: "friendInfo" 
      }
    },
    {$group:{
       _id:"$_id",
       friends:{$addToSet:{$arrayElemAt:["$friendInfo.name",0]}},
       name:{$first:"$name"}
      }
    }
]);
```

Comment: This only shows the first name inside the friends array, how would I see all the names?